# SQL Query to Show Item without a specific record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table of Products with item_Number as their primary key. Each items is assigned to a location and each item can be tagged into different categories.

I want to write a query to show item_number which DOES not have a category 'Small'. This is needed to know which item has no small category to be added later on, considering there are thousand of items in the database.

Here is the sample dataset for reference and example

```
Item_Number      Location   Category
A                East       Big
A                East       Small
A                East       Medium
B                East       Big
B                East       Medium
C                East       Big
C                East       Small
C                East       Medium
D                East       Big
D                East       Medium
```

Here's my initial code

```
select  item_Num, location 
from PRODUCT 
WHERE location  = 'East' and category <> 'Small'
```

That code returns

```
 Item_Number     Location   
    A                East       
    A                East       
    B                East      
    B                East       
    C                East       
    C                East       
    D                East       
    D                East
```

**Expected Result should be**

```
 Item_Number     Location   
    B                East      
    D                East
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grouping:

```
SELECT item_Num, 'East'  
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE location  = 'East' 
GROUP BY item_num
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'Small' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

`HAVING` clause is like a `WHERE` applied to a *group* of records having the same `item_num`. The predicate of the query checks for groups containing no `category = 'Small'` records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6ebe/1)

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery with not exists

```
select  distinct item_Num, location 
from PRODUCT a
WHERE location  = 'East' and not exists 
  (select 1 from PRODUCT b where a.item_Num=b.item_Num and b.Category='Small' 
      and b.location  = 'East')
```

OR you can try this one

```
select  item_Num, location 
from product
WHERE location  = 'East'
group by item_Num, location 
having sum(case when Category='Small' then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select t1.* from PRODUCT t1
where not exists ( select 1 from PRODUCT t2 where t1.Item_Number=t2.Item_Number and Category='Small')
and location='East'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_Num, location 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE location  = 'East' and Item_Number  Not in (SELECT Item_Number FROM PRODUCT  WHERE category ='Small')
```

Comment: If any issue the tell me.